# What does the term "beagles" mean in this WWI-era poem?

Tags: meaning, british-english

[Jessie Pope](https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-32298697)'s poem "'Ware Wire!" (seen on page 17 of [*Jessie Pope's War Poems*](https://archive.org/details/jessiepopeswarpo00popeiala), 1915) starts its description of trench warfare this way:

> **When the beagles are running like steam,**
>   When the plough is as sticky as glue,
>   When the scent is an absolute scream,
>   And there’s wire in the fence to get through—

What does it mean for "the beagles [to be] running like steam"?  "Running like steam" itself seems to be a common enough idiom — it means running quickly — but are we talking about actual beagle dogs here, or is this slang for something else? (This being WWI, it can't be slang for the [F-15E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F-15E_Strike_Eagle).)

I know dogs were used in WWI, but I wouldn't have expected beagles *specifically*, nor do I understand why an image of *beagles running quickly* would be a natural opening line for this poem about "our boys at the front."

And on the next line, I suppose the "plough" is a literal plough, maybe for [digging trenches](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBw3VDB7t9Q) or maybe involved somehow with cutting wire; or maybe it's just a mistake for "slough"?

At least I understand (or think I do) the reference to the *scent* of no-man's-land.

Comment: He was referring to the troops on the HMS Beagle who landed on the shores of France https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Beagle_(1909) In the first year of the war many British people were still enthusiastic, but soon they felt the war came to a stale mate, a pointless war struggling for terrain (i.e. the plough sticky as glue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "beagles" in the first stanza are to be read literally as dogs.

The first stanza describes a peace-time hunting scene. In a hunt (perhaps a fox hunt where beagles were typically used as scent hounds), you don't care if your buddy is getting torn by the wire fences through which you rush: "torn, muddy, and blown, every man on his own – that's the time-honoured rule of the run". Note that the word "run" is a giveaway here: according to the OED, it refers to "a spell of riding on horseback", especially "a ride (usually with hounds) forming a part of a hunt".

The second stanza contrasts this hunting scene with a war-time situation in France. Here, getting caught in a wire fence is no sport, with shots, shells and bullets everywhere. Contrary to the hunt, the men in this scene assist each other, and take the time to free a fellow soldier from a wire even under pressure.

The contrast is made explicit in the third stanza: Here, the poem summarizes how a sportsman will not wait for anyone left behind, as if the hunt was a "life and death run". But when facing true death – "black Eternity" –, "there's time and there's patience enough".

Comment: A great analysis that went entirely over my head before! (And Kate's answer likewise, but I'm accepting this one as being longer and more fleshed-out, breaking it down stanza by stanza to show the contrasts that I had missed completely.)

Answer (score 4):

Having tracked down the text of the poem, I don't think the first verse describes trench warfare. It refers to hunting on foot with a pack of beagles, across muddy ploughed fields and over barbed-wire fences. I think she is saying that, in those circumstances, a man would not stop to help a companion who had got his clothes caught on the wire, but in the trenches (described in verse 2) it was different because being caught in wire could be a matter of life and death.

Comment: Nice answer, Kate.  You beat me to exactly the same analysis by 3 minutes.  I agree completely, having just read up about hunting with beagles.